# Trying to show only the last 4 results of a table

Tags: php, break

I'm  new to PHP...
We have a table that get lots of rows with data and we need to show only the last 4 rows of it.

This is the code before the table:

```
while ($counter < $i) { // strat while loop, echo guests
                                if ($counter == 4) { break; }
```

right now it displays the first 4 rows

Note that we don't want to use SQL LIMIT 4 because the data can be changed from the user actions that we asks before the while.

Comment: can't you do using a reverse counter loop which starts from lengh-3,2,1,0?

Comment: The counter itself isn't the issue, even though this approach seems dirty. If you say that you now display the first 4 rows, but you want to display the last 4, then you should reverse the array (i guess, your code doesn't show it) before entering the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SQL ORDER BY id DESC - this will select your collection in reverce order. (or it could be other column instead id which you are using as primary key)

Comment: Reversing the table disables some of the "if" that we use from users actions... for example if user is not paying it shows a different data

Comment: well, you could use num_rows command to know the count of rows in your collection, and then in if loop show only last 4 elements (count-3, count-2, count-1 and count)